# Why is a document from a Cloud Firestore database not deleted?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following database structure:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- userId (document)
   |            |
   |            --- //user details
   |
   --- products (collection)
          |
          --- listId (document)
                 |
                 --- listProducts (collection)
                         |
                         --- productId
                                 |
                                 --- //product details
```

And I use the following code to delete the documents:

```
rootRef.collection("users").document(userId).delete(); //works fine
rootRef.collection("products").document(listId).delete();
```

The first line of code works perfectly but the second is not deleting the `list` document. Is it because it has a subcollection beneath it or am I doing something wrong?

How to delete the entire `listId` document together with everything it has beneath it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if your `listId` isn't null before you call the second line?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes It is not `null` for sure because I'm using that variable in other place and it has a value. Any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collections that are nested under a document, are not automatically deleted when you delete that document. When you *only* delete the document itself, the Firebase console will show the document ID in italic. The document itself isn't there anymore (you can see this when you select it, as it won't have any fields), but the nested collections are still accessible.

So I suspect that the `products` document is gone, but the nested collections still exist. As the [Firestore documentation on deleting collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections) describes, you'll need to delete the documents from the collection to get rid of it.

Comment: You are right! I solved the problem by getting a step lower in the tree to the `listProducts` collection and then I used `deleteCollection()` method as described in the link you gave me. Works perfectly! Thanks you!